# Symfony - Routing based on Subdomain?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have two subdomains pointing to the "web" directory in my Symfony 1.4 implementation and would like to route to certain modules/actions based which subdomain was used to arrive at the site

```
sub1.domain.com --> module1/action
sub2.domain.com --> module2/action
```

Is there an easy way to do this in routing.yml?  Customize index.php, parsing the host for subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this chapter](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing) in More With Symfony. It does essentially the same thing by creating a custom route that checks the subdomain... It uses the DB but you could omit that if you dont need to hit the DB.

Comment: Thanks. Not the simple yml config a Symfony newb was hoping for, but looks like it's the right approach

Comment: Its actually not that complex, i swear. :-) Just FYI if you wanted to switch apps as opposed to module/action youd want to look at filters or modifying the index.php... or additional .htaccess rules... which one of those three to choose would really depend on the situation.

Comment: I have a better understanding of your recommendations now, thanks.  Could you please review this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702414/how-to-structure-this-symfony-web-project

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather write an execution filter or custom routing class.

Check out this example: http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/02-Advanced-Routing